# How to search data of certain id in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For searching: First user have to select category and type something to search. The category id is passed to the controller. So, only the id of category needs to be shown while searching.
Eg: User Selects Automobiles category and search bikes. Then only bike result should be shown.
    WHen user selects Rent category and search bikes then it should not show the bike result.

**My code**

```
     foreach($a as $b)
            {  

                foreach($b->child as $c)
                {
                  //we can retrieve the id of category by "$c->id"
                   $data['ads'] = PostAd::where('adtitle','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')

                   ->get();

                }
            }
```

Comment: There is no `category`, `Automobiles`,`bike`

Comment: Do you have category column in the table

Comment: you want multiple where clause??

Comment: @Ikdhruw I have category table

Comment: @zahid hasan emon yes but it doesn't work like i mention in example

Comment: whats `a` `b` `c` in the code??

Comment: @A4family access `PostAd` through `Catagory` using Has-Many-Through relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple where clause.

```
$data['ads'] = PostAd::where('category_id',$category_id)
               ->where('adtitle','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
               ->get();
```

Or

```
$data['ads'] = PostAd::where([
                   ['category_id',$category_id],
                   ['adtitle','LIKE','%'.$search.'%']
               ])
               ->get();
```